# Is there a simple way to store html inside a data element?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
<a class="open-modal" href="#special-modal"
data-html="<p>HELLO</p> <strong>dddddddddddddddddd</strong><a
href=" http:="" www.google.com"="">asdas</a>
```

Tried to store some simple html and the html broke as a result, is there a way to change the string using php in order to be able to store any html inside a data element?

```
<a class="open-modal" href="#special-modal" data-html="<?= get_post_meta($post->ID, '_newproduct_data-html', false)[0] ?>"><?= esc_html_e('Modal', 'blacksmith'); ?></a>
```

Do I need to encode this the result of get_post_meta in php and then decode it using php when the modal opens up? Is there a better way?

Comment: Try base64 encoding the content maybe.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Rather than pollute the page with as needed content you might consider an ajax request in the modal opening code to get it when it is actually needed

Answer (score 0):

Just like the `e_html_e()` function you're using, there is an [`esc_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) function too, specifically for escaping HTML attribute values.

```
<a class="open-modal" href="#special-modal" data-html="<?= esc_attr(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_newproduct_data-html', false)[0]) ?>"><?= esc_html_e('Modal', 'blacksmith'); ?></a>
```

Note: `esc_attr()` is a WordPress-specific function (since the question is already using other WP-specific functions).